# How can I add variable names to the end of a file?

Tags: php, file

I have created a form that submits the data to a filename on the server.  The form submit is working fine, it generates the requested file called "we_input_.sts".

I am trying to use the following code to grab two variables from the form "bfstnme" and "gfstnme"and attach them to the filename eg "wed_import-Jane_Bill.sts

This is the amended code: However I am still unable to get it to work.

I am trying different ideas to get this to work correctly.   I have tried moving the code around but I'm still obviously missing something.  The last line before the $savestring== is "$fp=fopen("wed-import-.sts", "a+");
The last lines after the $savestring are : fwrite($fp,$savestring); fclose($fp);

```
<?php
$bfirstname = $_POST['bfstnme'];
$gfirstname = $_POST['gfstnme'];
$file = 'wed_import_.sts';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$new_file = 'wed_input_'.$bfirstname.'&amp;'.$gfirstname.'.sts';
file_put_contents($new_file, $current);
?>
```

Comment: I believe you will find the answer to this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972424/php-create-or-write-append-in-text-file)  (( [php create or write/append in text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972424/php-create-or-write-append-in-text-file) ))

Comment: Please specify exactly what goes wrong with your code. In what way does it not work? File not output; exception; wrong data ... ?

Comment: Thank you for commenting.  The file with the correct data is being created without the inserted variables.  I will try the suggestion below.

Comment: @Ivan Conway you got some advance?

Comment: Hello Adrian, I have tried different variations of the following code and am able to create the required filename, however I am still unable to call the required $savestring  values into the file.  The php code works perfectly without the following code and generates the required "wed_import_.sts" file with all of the $savestring data in it..  I am obviously missing something or not putting the code in the right place.

Comment: I am currently trying variations of this without success.     (.$bfstnme'_'.$gfstnme);
$fp = fopen("wed_import_($names).sts", "a+");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want put the info inside the file you must change the + by a . like this:

$current .= ("gfirstname" . "bfirstname");

If you want change the name, you must do something like @Jay_P says

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I have solved it using the valuable assistance of all concerned.

```
$names .= ("$bfstnme" . "$gfstnme");
$fp = fopen("wed_import_($names).sts", "a+");
```

The results of the above give me a filename called:
"wed_Import_[JaneBill].sts.  I only need to work out how to put an amperstand (&) betwen the names.
Thank you to all.

Comment: do this `$names .= ("$bfstnme" ."&". "$gfstnme");`

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't name the file before writing to it?

```
<?php
   $gfirstname = $_POST['gname'];
   $bfirstname = $_POST['bname'];
   $file = 'wed_input_Bride_Groom.sts';
   // Opens the file to get existing content hopefully
   $current = file_get_contents($file);
   // Appends bride and groom first names to the file hopefully
  $current .= ("gfirstname" . "bfirstname");
  $new_file = 'wed_input_'.$gfirstname.'_'.$bfirstname.'.sts';
  // Write the contents back to the file
 file_put_contents($new_file, $current);
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is more logical than the way I was going.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: Thank you to all who have helped me.  I now have the code working. Ivan

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have the names in a variable called `$names`.  You can easily append the text with the FILE_APPEND flag like this:

```
file_put_contents('wed_input_Bride_Groom.sts', $names, FILE_APPEND);
```