# How to write multiple line output in php?

Tags: php, asterisk

I want to write output of command in to php file.But when I open file only one line of output is written.

```
  $myfile = fopen("status1.txt", "a+"); 
  $cmd="asterisk -rx 'sip show peers'|greo OK";

  $test1=system($cmd);
  fwrite($myfile, $test1);
  fclose($myfile);
```

OUTPUT is

```
1004  /1004     (Unspecified)                            D                 0         OK                                  
1005  /1005     (Unspecified)                            D   N             0         OK                                  
1006  /1006     (Unspecified)                            D   N             0         OK                                  
2501  /2501     (Unspecified)                            D                 0         OK                                  
2502  /2502     (Unspecified)                            D   a             0         OK                                  
2503  /2503     (Unspecified)                            D   a             0         OK                                  
2504  /2504     (Unspecified)                            D                 0         OK
```

But In file only first line is written

Comment: possible duplicate of [php create or write/append in text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972424/php-create-or-write-append-in-text-file)

Comment: You need to append. Check the previous question mentioned from duplicate comment

Comment: @TrungNguyen he used `a+` meaning pointer is at the end of file and it does not truncate to zero.

Comment: have you tried using `\r\n` before `$test1` ? have you tried using `a` instead of `a+` ?

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://php.net/system). It says `Returns the last line of the command output on success`. So `$test1` will only be the last line of the command's output.

Comment: i do it like this.fwrite($myfile, "\n\r"$test1);

Comment: @JonStirling yes it is.so how can I get whole output?

Comment: @soni8010 [exec()](http://php.net/exec) should do the trick.

Comment: @JonStirling it works with shell_exec.Thanks for notifying me

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the exec function instead of system

e.g.

```
exec($cmd,scanme);
$scanme = implode("\n",$scanme);
```

exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )

Your case:

```
  $myfile = fopen("status1.txt", "a+"); 
  $cmd="asterisk -rx 'sip show peers'|greo OK";

  exec($cmd,$test1);
  $test1 = implode("\n",$test1);

  fwrite($myfile, $test1);
  fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: i dont think this is the problem .