# php User registration system without mysql database

Tags: php

I want to create a registration system on my site where only limited users will be able to create their account. I  want to use a .txt file  for storing usernames and passwords.

I have the following code so far :

```
$uname=$_POST['usr'];
$pass=$_POST['pwd'];

if(empty($_POST["ok"])){echo "Could not insert data!";}
 else
{$file=fopen("user.txt","w");
echo fwrite($file,$uname);
fclose($file);}
```

This receives the user data from a form and puts it in user.txt file.

My problem is that when new data is inserted to txt file the old data get deleted.

I want to keep the data in txt file like

```
  foo:12345~bar:1111
```

username and password are seprated by **:** and new user is seprated by **~** ,later I will use regex to get the data from txt file.

How can i  correct my code to keep both new and old data?

Comment: You need to open file in append mode http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php create or write/append in text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972424/php-create-or-write-append-in-text-file)

Comment: **plain text stored password are evil** use some [hashing function](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php); custom storage standard too, **use CSV with [fputscv](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fputcsv.php)** ; file storage custom engine is **really weak on concurrent write** use sqlite or other atomic tool

Answer (score 2):

You need to open file in append mode

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

```
<?php

$uname = $_POST['usr'];
$pass = $_POST['pwd'];

if (empty($_POST["ok"])) {
    echo "Could not insert data!";
} else {
    $file = fopen("user.txt", "a");
    $srt="foo:".$uname."~bar:".$pass;// create your string 
    echo fwrite($file, $srt);
    fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @saty , you have solved a part of my proble, now old data is not getting deleted. but it put the data as **foo:user~bar:1234** i want to update the foo column with $uname, and 1234 with $pwd ,~bar:1234 will be for next user registration.

Answer (score 1):

> If we want to add on to a file we need to open it up in append mode.

So you need to change from write only mode to append mode.

```
$file=fopen("user.txt","a");
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: you have to explicitly pass `$mode` argument to `fopen()` function equals to `'a'`.

However, it looks like a bad idea to use plain files for this task. Mainly because of concurent writes troubles.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a bad choice: there are a lot of drawbacks for security, for read/write times, for concurrent requests and a lot more.
Using a database isn't difficult, so my suggestion is to use one.

Anyway, your question is asked yet here: [php create or write/append in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24972424/1399706)

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to append to a file:

```
file_put_contents("C:/file.txt", "this is a text line" . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```