# read CSV rows and delimiter -> read and split after every second element

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv like this:

```
A,1
B,2
C,3
D,4
e,5
...
```

How do I append a "," before each new line - and then split the file after every second element?

so that I get:
`A,B,C,D,E` ... in one file and
`1,2,3,4,5` ... in another?

fopen, fgetcsv and fputcsv I get - but in between?

Comment: Just read the whole thing in a two-dimensional array, and then use array_column … and write the two resulting arrays back into individual files.

Comment: Unless the file is HUGE and blows your memory limit

Comment: Why do you want to append a comma before each new line?

Comment: A little confused !! Your _so that I get:_ example does not seem to match with your requirement _How do I append a "," before each new line - and then split the file after every second element_

Comment: I think he's making it harder than it has to be and making it one giant comma separated string and trying to split it up that way.

Comment: @Lulceltech: yes, you´re right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small file, just put it in an array as suggested.

Large file?
Then read here how you can open a large file:
[Reading very large files in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162176/reading-very-large-files-in-php)

> Did 2 tests with a 1.3GB file and a 9.5GB File.
>
> 1.3 GB
>
> Using fopen()
>
> This process used 15555 ms for its computations.
>
> It spent 169 ms in system calls.
>
> Using file()
>
> This process used 6983 ms for its computations.
>
> It spent 4469 ms in system calls.
>
> 9.5 GB
>
> Using fopen()
>
> This process used 113559 ms for its computations.
>
> It spent 2532 ms in system calls.
>
> Using file()
>
> This process used 8221 ms for its computations.
>
> It spent 7998 ms in system calls.
>
> Seems file() is faster.

Now process the file line by line. For every line, just use:

```
$linearr = explode(",",$line);
```

Now add `$line[0]` to the end of outputfile 1 and `$line[1]` to the end of outputfile 2.

Two ways to do the appending are described here:
[Create or write/append in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972424/create-or-write-append-in-text-file)

```
$txt = "user id date";  
$myfile = file_put_contents('logs.txt',$txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

or

```
$myfile = fopen("logs.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!"); 
$txt = "user id date"; 
fwrite($myfile, "\n". $txt); 
fclose($myfile);
```