# why can't I get stripe webhook response

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks

So I am new with stripe, I am trying to get the checkout payment intent response using webhook 
my purpose is to send the checkout response to my dashboard angular application so that I can save data about the client and it's payment whether it is successful or not  
so I used this code :

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_xxx');

$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event = null;

try {
    $event = \Stripe\Event::constructFrom(
        json_decode($payload, true)
    );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    // Invalid payload
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
}

$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event = null;

try {
    $event = \Stripe\Event::constructFrom(
        json_decode($payload, true)
    );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    // Invalid payload
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
}
print_r($payload);
// Handle the event
switch ($event->type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        $paymentIntent = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentIntent
echo 'success';
        // Then define and call a method to handle the successful payment intent.
        // handlePaymentIntentSucceeded($paymentIntent);
        break;
    case 'payment_intent.payment_failed':
        $paymentMethod = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentMethod
echo 'failed';
        // Then define and call a method to handle the successful attachment of a PaymentMethod.
        // handlePaymentMethodAttached($paymentMethod);
        break;
    // ... handle other event types
    default:
        // Unexpected event type
        http_response_code(400);
        exit();
}

http_response_code(200);
```

then I run a checkout test and after I finished and got the success page I tried to access www.website.com/webhooks.php it always gives me a 400 error,
I don't know if what I am doing is wrong or not and how the uses webhooks I am still figuring it so can some one tell me what to do

Comment: It makes little sense to try and “access” this webhook script via your browser address bar. That will cause a GET request, but the script expects to get JSON data POSTed to it. JSON-decoding the non-existing payload will probably only get you null or false, and trying to create a stripe event based on that will then simply throw an exception, so you get the 400 response.

Comment: so I need to make a post request right? but from where should I send it and with what parameters?

Comment: _“so I need to make a post request right?”_ – if you want to debug your script, by sending it a set of test data yourself, then you could do that, yes. (But you are aware that this is not how a webhook actually works, in practice, right? _Their_ system would make the POST request to yours.) _“and with what parameters?”_ - that should be explained somewhere in their API documentation.

Comment: it's the first time that I use a webhook and I don't know how it works

Comment: Then you should do some reading up on that first of all. There are plenty explanations available if you just google a bit.

Comment: thank you for your help now I understand how webhooks works

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So the problem with my code is that I should not access www.website.com/webhooks.php to get my response, instead, I should store the response into a database or a file or send it somewhere  like so :

```
    <?php
    require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_xxxx');

    $payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
    $event = null;

    try {
        $event = \Stripe\Event::constructFrom(
            json_decode($payload, true)
        );
    } catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
        // Invalid payload
        http_response_code(400);
        exit();
    }

    $payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
    $event = null;

    try {
        $event = \Stripe\Event::constructFrom(
            json_decode($payload, true)
        );
    } catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
        // Invalid payload
        http_response_code(400);
        exit();
    }
    print_r($payload);
    // Handle the event
    switch ($event->type) {
        case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
            $paymentIntent = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentIntent
    //echo 'success';
            // Then define and call a method to handle the successful payment intent.
            $msg='success';
            handlePaymentIntentSucceeded($paymentIntent,$msg);
            break;
        case 'payment_intent.payment_failed':
            $paymentMethod = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentMethod

            $msg='failed';
            handlePaymentIntentSucceeded($paymentMethod,$msg);
            // Then define and call a method to handle the successful attachment of a PaymentMethod.
            // handlePaymentMethodAttached($paymentMethod);
            break;
        case 'payment_intent.canceled':
            $paymentMethod = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentMethod

            $msg='canceled';
            handlePaymentIntentSucceeded($paymentMethod,$msg);
            // Then define and call a method to handle the successful attachment of a PaymentMethod.
            // handlePaymentMethodAttached($paymentMethod);
            break;
        // ... handle other event types
        case 'payment_intent.created':
            $paymentMethod = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentMethod

            $msg='created';
            handlePaymentIntentSucceeded($paymentMethod,$msg);
            // Then define and call a method to handle the successful attachment of a PaymentMethod.
            // handlePaymentMethodAttached($paymentMethod);
            break;
        case 'payment_intent.processing':
            $paymentMethod = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentMethod

            $msg='processing';
            handlePaymentIntentSucceeded($paymentMethod,$msg);
            // Then define and call a method to handle the successful attachment of a PaymentMethod.
            // handlePaymentMethodAttached($paymentMethod);
            break;

        default:
            // Unexpected event type
            http_response_code(400);
            exit();
    }

    http_response_code(200);


    function handlePaymentIntentSucceeded($paymentIntent,$status){


        $data=[
            'amount'=>$paymentIntent->amount,
            'name'=>$paymentIntent->charges->data[0]->billing_details->name,
            'email'=>$paymentIntent->charges->data[0]->billing_details->email,
            'error'=>$paymentIntent->last_payment_error->message,
            'status'=>$status

        ];
        $date=date("Y/m/d");

        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    // db credentials
        define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
        define('DB_USER', 'root');
        define('DB_PASS', '');
        define('DB_NAME', 'database');

    // Connect with the database.
        function connect()
        {
            $connect = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

            if (mysqli_connect_errno($connect)) {
                die("Failed to connect:" . mysqli_connect_error());
            }
            mysqli_set_charset($connect, "utf8");

            return $connect;
        }

        $con = connect();




        // Store data into a database .
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `ordre`( `amount`, `email`, `name`, `status`, `msg`, `date`) VALUES ({$data['amount']},'{$data['email']}','{$data['name']}','{$data['status']}',\"{$data['error']}\",'{$date}')";



        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
            http_response_code(201);
//to check if the storage process is done and
            $myFile = "https://6537bee0.ngrok.io/file.txt";
            $myFileLink2 = fopen($myFile2, 'w+') or die("Can't open file.");
            $newnbord ='done';
            fwrite($myFileLink2, $newnbord);
            fclose($myFileLink2);
            return $newnbord ;
        }
        else
        {  http_response_code(422);
            // write error code in a file
            http_response_code(201);
            $myFile2 = "https://6537bee0.ngrok.io/file.txt";
            $myFileLink2 = fopen($myFile2, 'w+') or die("Can't open file.");
            $newnbord =mysqli_error($con).$sql
            ;
            fwrite($myFileLink2, $newnbord);
            fclose($myFileLink2);
            return $newnbord ;

        }


    }
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Stripe CLI](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli) to [trigger a test event](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/test#forward-events) to your endpoint, or even to [test locally by forwarding](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/test#listen-for-events). You can also send test webhooks from your Stripe dashboard in the Webhooks section.

You should add some logging and [write to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972424/create-or-write-append-in-text-file) to check the event processing to debug.

Comment: I recommend sending test events from the Stripe dashboard. This is how this should be done. +1

Comment: thank you for your advice, I already tried that, but my problem was that I did not understand how  to use webhooks and how to receive the response and show it without Stripe CLI so I tried to write the response into a file and I got my response now