# Create New Array if one exists

Tags: php, json

Hello I Have This Php Code:

```
$Name = $_POST["Name"];
$sobrenome = $_POST["sobrenome"];
$data_time = $_POST["data_time"];
$data = array(
    array(
        "nome" => $Name,
        "sobrenome" => $sobrenome ,
        "data" => $data,
    ),
);
$arquivo = 'form.json';
$json = json_encode($data);
$file = fopen(__DIR__ . '/' . $arquivo,'w');
fwrite($file, $json);
fclose($file);
```

as you can see it converts my form into an array and saves it in a json file so far so good, but the problem is that if I send the form more than once it subscribes to the current data, how could I create a new array each  does it already exist?

edit: here's an example, suppose when i sent the form the first time i put the value in nome: Nicolas and Sobrenome: Baiger and last in data_time i put 18:31, so form.json would look like this:

```
'[{"nome":"Nicolas", "Sobrenome":"Baiger", data_time:"18:31"}]'
```

Now if I put in the nome: Jhon in the Sobrenome: Clynton and in data_time: 12:30 and I submit the form a second time it would overwrite all the other data that I had previously put in like this:

```
'[{"nome":"Jhon", "Sobrenome":"Clynton", data_time:"12:30"}]'
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly, but it seems to me you want to [append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972424/create-or-write-append-in-text-file) to the file?

Comment: yes, but before I want to create a new array if items already exist in json

Comment: You mean you want to update some values? It's really not clear what you're asking, can you show it on a simplified example?

Comment: here is an example if if there is a key "nome" in form.json it creates a new array that also has the key "nome" because the way my code is it is overwriting the data and I do not want it to subscribe to  Dice!

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't clear things up. Please edit the question and give an example of how the file should look like after one and after two submissions.

Comment: @El_Vanja I already edited the post to see if it was clearer!

Comment: This confirms my first impression, you just want to append a new entry (add new information to the end of the file). The question I linked to and the answer you got here both show how to append.

Answer (score 0):

The description kinda blur, but I guess there are two possibilities:

1. Append the second post into form.json.

change $file = fopen(**DIR** . '/' . $arquivo,'w') to:

```
$file = fopen(__DIR__ . '/' . $arquivo,'a');
```

2. use a different json file:

change $arquivo = 'form.json'; to :

```
$arquivo = random_int(100,999) . 'json';
```